# writing from one file to another log lines with conditions

Tags: java

I have problem with writing lines from one file to another file specyfic line of 
my log.

My log file have structure:

```
some data
some data
<tag which I am interested in>
important data
</tag which I am interested in>
some data
some data
```

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "myImputLog.log";
        readWriteFile(filePath);
    }
    public static void readWriteFile(String filePath){
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            FileWriter fileWriter =new FileWriter("myOutPut.txt");
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(line);
                if ((line.matches("(?i).*<tag which I am interested in>.*"))){
                    fileWriter.write(line);
                    fileWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());
                }
                if ((line.matches("(?i).*</tag which I am interested in>.*"))){
                    fileWriter.write(line);
                    fileWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }
            fileReader.close();
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How to write to file everything which contains 'tag which I am interested in' ?

Comment: Is the input which you have described an xml file?  Specifically somedata which you have mentioned is it also xml?

Comment: You are only writing the lines that match the XML tags.  You want to ignore those lines.  Instead, set a flag like `startWrite = true` then continue reading and write all those lines until you hit the /XML.  When you do set `startWrite = false`.